# Helm Find Files: prefer certain extensions

Tags: helm, find-file

Helm find files lists files of the same name alphabetically.

```
a.aux
a.log
a.tex
b.aux
b.log
b.tex
```

This is annoying as I want the `.tex` file 99% of the time. Is it possible to prefer certain extensions (by white- or blacklist) to either change the order for extensions only:

```
a.tex (prefered)
a.aux
a.log
b.tex (prefered)
b.aux
b.log
```

, or even "surpassing" filename priority, like so:

```
a.tex (prefered)
b.tex (prefered)
a.aux
a.log
b.aux
b.log
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the current code AFAIK (see `helm-ff-initial-sort-method`). One solution that doesn't require using a sorting algorithm is to append two lists, one containing the tex files and the other one containing the non-tex files so that the tex files are always on top.

```
(advice-add 'helm-list-directory :filter-return
            (lambda (files)
              (let ((tex-files (cl-remove-if-not
                                (lambda (f)
                                  (string= (file-name-extension f) "tex"))
                                files))
                    (non-tex-files (cl-remove-if
                                    (lambda (f)
                                      (string= (file-name-extension f) "tex"))
                                    files)))
                (append tex-files non-tex-files))))
```

Comment: Very informative and provides exactly what the OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

When using something like helm-projectile-find-file-dwim I would just add .tex as another search seed. In Helm FF, type the ext after the trailing eg "x/y/.tex" Not quite what you want but close.

Comment: This works for searching specific extensions, yes. But I **almost always** want the `.tex` over the `.aux` or `.log` files, so want to avoid having it to type every time